# SXA 1.5 htmlCache not working

Tags: sxa, caching

On a brand new Sitecore 8.2.5 + SXA 1.5 on Azure, deployed from the Sitecore templates, I cannot make the htmlCache working.
The [html] cache stays empty.

Has anyone encountered the same?

Comment: Have you enabled the cache and set some renderings to be able to cache?

Comment: did you navigate to sitecore/content/tenant/site/settings/Site Grouping/site, and in the Flags section, select the Cache Html check box ?

Comment: Yes, I did both.